# Finding local maximum points of a given data set

Tags: ios, swift, algorithm, matlab, accelerometer

So I embarked on a quest to calculate the number of steps taken by a user by using the data I get from the accelerometer i.e **x**, **y** and **z** coordinates.

I am trying to implement [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlabmobile_android/ug/counting-steps-by-capturing-acceleration-data.html) algorithm but I am currently stuck at the local maxima portion. Matlab has a built in `findpeaks()`method which locates all the local maxima of a given data set.

Below is my attempt at implementing the algorithm but I still get extremely enormous results from it.
At first, using a data set which consisted of `20` actual steps, the algorithm calculated that the number of steps taken was `990+`. I tweaked and debugged it and I managed to bring this number down to around `660`..then `110` finally to a current `45`. Currently I am just stuck and have a feeling that my `findpeaks()` method is wrong.

This is my class implementation

```
import Foundation

class StepCounter
{
   private var xAxes: [Double] = [Double]()
   private var yAxes: [Double] = [Double]()
   private var zAxes: [Double] = [Double]()
   private var rmsValues: [Double] = [Double]()

  init(graphPoints: GraphPoints)
 {
    xAxes = graphPoints.xAxes
    yAxes = graphPoints.yAxes
    zAxes = graphPoints.zAxes
    rmsValues = graphPoints.rmsValues
 }

func numberOfSteps()-> Int
{
    var pointMagnitudes: [Double] = rmsValues
    
    removeGravityEffectsFrom(&pointMagnitudes)
    
    let minimumPeakHeight: Double = standardDeviationOf(pointMagnitudes)
    
    let peaks = findPeaks(&pointMagnitudes)
    
    var totalNumberOfSteps: Int = Int()
    
    for thisPeak in peaks
    {
        if thisPeak > minimumPeakHeight
        {
            totalNumberOfSteps += 1
        }
    }
    
    return totalNumberOfSteps
}

// TODO: dummy method for the time being. replaced with RMS values from controller itself
private func calculateMagnitude()-> [Double]
{
    var pointMagnitudes: [Double] = [Double]()
    
    for i in 0..<xAxes.count
    {
        let sumOfAxesSquare: Double = pow(xAxes[i], 2) + pow(yAxes[i], 2) + pow(zAxes[i], 2)
        pointMagnitudes.append(sqrt(sumOfAxesSquare))
    }
    
    return pointMagnitudes
}

private func removeGravityEffectsFrom(inout magnitudesWithGravityEffect: [Double])
{
    let mean: Double = calculateMeanOf(rmsValues)
    
    for i in 0..<magnitudesWithGravityEffect.count
    {
        magnitudesWithGravityEffect[i] -= mean
    }
}

// Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation
private func standardDeviationOf(magnitudes: [Double])-> Double
{
    var sumOfElements: Double = Double()
    var mutableMagnitudes: [Double] = magnitudes
    
    // calculates the numerator of the equation
    /* no need to do (mutableMagnitudes[i] = mutableMagnitudes[i] - mean) 
     * because it has already been done when the gravity effect was removed
     * from the dataset
     */
    for i in 0..<mutableMagnitudes.count
    {
        mutableMagnitudes[i] = pow(mutableMagnitudes[i], 2)
    }
    
    // sum the elements
    for thisElement in mutableMagnitudes
    {
        sumOfElements += thisElement
    }
    
    let sampleVariance: Double = sumOfElements/Double(mutableMagnitudes.count)
    
    return sqrt(sampleVariance)
}

// Reference: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html#examples
private func findPeaks(inout magnitudes: [Double])-> [Double]
{
    var peaks: [Double] = [Double]()
    
    // ignore the first element
    peaks.append(max(magnitudes[1], magnitudes[2]))
    
    for i in 2..<magnitudes.count
    {
        if i != magnitudes.count - 1
        {
            peaks.append(max(magnitudes[i], magnitudes[i - 1], magnitudes[i + 1]))
        }
        else
        {
            break
        }
    }
    
    // TODO:Does this affect the number of steps? Are they clumsly lost or foolishly added?
    peaks = Array(Set(peaks)) // removing duplicates.
    
    return peaks
}

private func calculateMeanOf(magnitudes: [Double])-> Double
{
    var sumOfElements: Double = Double()
    
    for thisElement in magnitudes
    {
        sumOfElements += thisElement
    }
    
    return sumOfElements/Double(magnitudes.count)
}
```

}`

With this [datasheet](http://pastebin.com/DBE1JYRu), the actual number of steps taken was `20` but I keep getting around `45`. Even when I tried it with a dataset that consists of `30` actual steps, the calculated number was approaching the `100s.`

Any assistance/guidance will be greatly appreciated

**PS**: Datasheet format is **X**,**Y**,**Z**,**RMS**(root mean square)

Comment: Because I am trying to implement the Matlab built-in `findpeaks()` method in iOS

Comment: In your `findPeaks` method, why are you doing this: `peaks.append(max(magnitudes[i], magnitudes[i - 1], magnitudes[i + 1]))`? Shouldn't you only be appending the value if the max is `magnitudes[i ]`?

Comment: *"Are they clumsly lost or foolishly added?"* Both. It's certainly possible that two unrelated peaks will have the same value, in which case you'll be throwing away valid peaks. On the other hand, if the data has minuscule  oscillations it in, you'll count too many peaks. For example, this data has a peak at 36, but you'll count 3 peaks: 33,34,33,34,35,34,35,36,35,34,35,34,33,34,33.

Comment: @jjatie According to this [example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html#examples) they skip the first element then check the second element. Compare it with `i`, `i+1` and itself then finds out that `15` is large hence adds it to the peaks array. `i` now points to `15` then checks if `8`, `15` or `5` is larger than `15` which is not true hence doesn't add and goes forth. Isn't this what its doing?Or am I completely wrong?

Comment: @user3386109 I did notice that and I will get to fixing it but thanks for the illustration. Would you recommend not removing duplicates then? Because keeping them brings about the issue of counting steps twice. Or would removing duplicates from the magnitudes array prior to finding peaks make more sense?

Comment: I would apply a [smoothing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothing) to the data before looking for the peaks. The easiest to implement is the [simple moving average](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Simple_moving_average).

Comment: I'll get right on it. I really appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function works with the example you provided. It treats plateaus as one peak, and allows for multiple peaks of the same value. The only problem is as — @user3386109 points outs — if there are lots of little oscillations in the data you will get more peaks than are really there. You might want to implement variance of the dataset in this calculation if you will be dealing with data like that.

Also, since you aren't changing the variable you pass in there is no need to use `inout`

```
private func findPeaks(magnitudes: [Double]) -> [Double] {

    var peaks = [Double]()
    // Only store initial point, if it is larger than the second. You can ignore in most data sets 
    if max(magnitudes[0], magnitudes[1]) == magnitudes[0] { peaks.append(magnitudes[0]) }

    for i in 1..<magnitudes.count - 2 {
        let maximum = max(magnitudes[i - 1], magnitudes[i], magnitudes[i + 1])
        // magnitudes[i] is a peak iff it's greater than it's surrounding points 
        if maximum == magnitudes[i] && magnitudes[i] != magnitudes[i+1] {
            peaks.append(magnitudes[i])
        }
    }
    return peaks
}
```

**UPDATE**
I noticed that my solution would not find a local maxima at the end of the collection. I have updated it and implemented it as an extension on `Collection`. This could easily be adapted to `Sequence` though I'm not sure that makes sense.

```
extension Collection where Element: Comparable {
    func localMaxima() -> [Element] {
        return localMaxima(in: startIndex..<endIndex)
    }

    func localMaxima(in range: Range<Index>) -> [Element] {
        var slice = self[range]
        var maxima = [Element]()

        var previousIndex: Index? = nil
        var currentIndex = slice.startIndex
        var nextIndex = slice.index(after: currentIndex)

        while currentIndex < slice.endIndex {
            defer {
                previousIndex = currentIndex
                currentIndex = nextIndex
                nextIndex = slice.index(after: nextIndex)
            }

            let current = slice[currentIndex]
            let next = slice[nextIndex]

            // For the first element, there is no previous
            if previousIndex == nil, Swift.max(current, next) == current {
                maxima.append(current)
                continue
            }

            // For the last element, there is no next
            if nextIndex == slice.endIndex {
                let previous = slice[previousIndex!]
                if Swift.max(previous, current) == current {
                    maxima.append(current)
                }
                continue
            }

            let previous = slice[previousIndex!]

            let maximum = Swift.max(previous, current, next)
            // magnitudes[i] is a peak iff it's greater than it's surrounding points
            if maximum == current && current != next {
                maxima.append(current)
            }
        }
        return maxima
    }
}
```

For what it's worth, here's an extension on `Sequence`

```
extension Sequence where Element: Comparable {
    func localMaxima() -> [Element] {
        var maxima = [Element]()
        var iterator = self.makeIterator()

        var previous: Element? = nil
        guard var current = iterator.next() else { return [] }
        while let next = iterator.next() {
            defer {
                previous = current
                current = next
            }

            // For the first element, there is no previous
            if previous == nil, Swift.max(current, next) == current {
                maxima.append(current)
                continue
            }

            let maximum = Swift.max(previous!, current, next)
            // magnitudes[i] is a peak iff it's greater than it's surrounding points
            if maximum == current && current != next {
                maxima.append(current)
            }
        }

        // For the last element, there is no next
        if Swift.max(previous!, current) == current {
            maxima.append(current)
        }

        return maxima
    }
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SOOOOO MUCH..SERIOUSLY. I would have broken the up-vote button if I had enough S/O reps. THANK YOU SO MUCH.

Comment: I do not understand this line `if maximum == magnitudes[i] && magnitudes[i] != magnitudes[i+1]`. If you are trying to find the maximum in the neighborhood shouldn't you be using `<` instead of `!=` to compare the value with the next one?

Comment: another thing is this: shouldn't the maxima return just one value instead of an array? I understand that the code was created to find the first local maxima, right?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is based off of @jjatie’s answer. It fixes issues I had with optionals being nil unexpectedly and adds an internal flag to allow suppressing the last maximum if it’s the last element.

I needed this last bit, because in my case it was just the rising edge and not really a maximum.

It also returns the indexes instead of the values. The relevant parts I’ve just been commented out. You can change it back easily, if you need that. You could even have the code return pairs if you need that. It’s really easy to get the actual value for an index though.

See the sample data that is included. It highlights all the issues I have found. You can try it with the original answer, if you’re curious.

The code was written in iPad Swift Playgrounds. That’s why it may look wonky.

```
extension Collection where Element: Comparable {
    func localMaximaIndexes() -> [Index] {
        return localMaximaIndexes(in: startIndex..<endIndex)
    }
    
    func localMaximaIndexes(in range: Range<Index>) -> [Index] {
        let wantLastElementIfLocalMaximum = false
        
        var slice = self[range]
        //var maxima = [Element]()
        var indexes = [Index]()
        
        var previousIndex: Index? = nil
        var currentIndex = slice.startIndex
        var nextIndex = slice.index(after: currentIndex)
        
        while currentIndex < slice.endIndex {
            defer {
                previousIndex = currentIndex
                currentIndex = nextIndex
                nextIndex = slice.index(after: nextIndex)
            }
            
            let current = slice[currentIndex]
            
            // For the last element, there is no next.
            if nextIndex == slice.endIndex {
                if wantLastElementIfLocalMaximum, 
                   let previousIndex = previousIndex {
                    let previous = slice[previousIndex]
                    if Swift.max(previous, current) == current {
                        //maxima.append(current)
                        indexes.append(currentIndex)
                    }
                }
                
                continue
            }
            
            let next = slice[nextIndex]
            
            // For the first element, there is no previous.
            if previousIndex == nil {
                if Swift.max(current, next) == current {
                    //maxima.append(current)
                    indexes.append(currentIndex)
                }
                
                continue
            }
            
            let previous = slice[previousIndex!]
            
            let maximum = Swift.max(previous, current, next)
            // magnitudes[i] is a peak iff it's greater than it's surrounding points.
            if maximum == current && current != next {
                //maxima.append(current)
                indexes.append(currentIndex)
            }
        }
        
        return indexes
    }
}

typealias Sample = Float

let result: [Sample]  = [-1.1324883e-06, 3.0614667, 5.6568537, 7.391036, 8.0, 7.391037, 5.6568546, 3.0614676, 5.5134296e-07, -3.0614667, -5.6568537, -7.391036, -8.0, -7.3910365, -5.6568546, -3.0614681, -4.3213367e-07, 3.0614672, 5.3033004, 6.4671564, 6.5, 5.543277, 3.8890872, 1.9134172, -1.937151e-07, -1.5307341, -2.474874, -2.7716386, -2.5, -1.847759, -1.06066, -0.38268328]

let maximaIndexes = result.localMaximaIndexes()
```